# How to upload files using protractor on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: protractor, ubuntu-16.04

[image]This is my code :

```
var path = require('path');
        var fileToUpload = protractor.basePath+'/home/raghavendra/Downloads/gayle_laakmann_-_business_resume.doc';
        var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);
        element.all(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
        browser.sleep(5000);
```

When am executing this test case it's showing test is passed but it is not uploading.

Comment: The test passes because there are no expectations to fail. But just waiting won't upload the file, you need to e.g. click the form submit button.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How to click on the submit button when i don't have html element.  Once opening the window I have to select the file and click on open button.help me with code. Please refer screen shot

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to *not trigger the "choose file" dialog* which you cannot control. Instead, *send keys to the appropriate `input` element* with `type="file"` and then *submit the form* (if not automatically submitted):

```
var fileInput = $('input[type=file]');
fileInput.sendKeys(absolutePath);

fileInput.submit();  // would submit the form
```

And make sure that the `input[type=file]` locator is good enough and you are actually targeting the desired `input` (check if there is a single element matching the locator).

Answer (score 0):

[Sending keys](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys) should be on a single element and not an [element array finder](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder).

```
        var path = require('path');
        var fileToUpload = protractor.basePath+'/home/raghavendra/Downloads/gayle_laakmann_-_business_resume.doc';
        var absolutePath = path.resolve(fileToUpload);
        element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

To submit the file, if there is an upload button on your website, then I would send a click to that one. If you are automating a drag and drop file onto a website to upload, then I would recommend also sending the return key.